# Foreach loop through multidimentional array like this

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array in variable `$comments`, containing:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 889
            [1] => First comment
            [2] => 8128912812
            [3] => appr
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 201
            [1] => This is the second comment
            [2] => 333333
            [3] => appr
        )

    // There is more...
)
```

How do I loop through this array and echo each value using for each?

Comment: Can you change the array to have appropriate keys? (id,text,user_id,meaning_of_index_3)

Comment: @KA_lin No, too late :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array structre stay like the one you show, you can do this like follow :

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment[0];
    echo $comment[1];
    echo $comment[2];
    echo $comment[3];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($arrayOfArrays as $array){
    foreach($array as $index => $value){
        echo $array[$index];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I echo each value of each array?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The above code will echo each value in each of your arrays.

Comment: Please see the answer by Mayous, I mean echo values separately like that. How can I do this in your approach?

Comment: See my edit, you can add the `$index` to the foreach. I'm not sure why you need to do this though if you can just echo the `$value` itself, but is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson did any of these responses answer your question? If so you should accept one of them as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use two `foreach` loops as your array has to levels :

```
foreach ($comments as $comment)
   foreach ($comment as $comment_data)
       echo $comment_data;
```

Comment: But how do I echo each value of each array?

Comment: @Henrik Petterson : What do you mean? This code should `echo` each value.

Comment: Please see the answer by Mayous, I mean echo values separately like that. How can I do this in your approach?

Comment: @Henrik Petterson : My approach does exactly the same thing but with less code and it is also a general solution, in case inner arrays have different number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two foreach loops. One inside the other

```
foreach($comments as $commentArray){
    foreach($commentArray as $comment){
        echo $comment; 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
$c=count($array);
while ($i<$c) {
   foreach ($array[$i] as $comment_property) {
echo $comment_property;
}
$i++;
}
```